# Indefinite Integral of $1 / \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c}$ with respect to $x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need to check whether my evaluation of $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} }$ is correct.

This is what I have evaluated.

First we note that the integral is defined only when $a x^2 + b x + c > 0$, so it will be assumed throughout that this is the case.

I have also omitted the constant of integration out of typical childish laziness.

a) For $a > 0$ we have the following:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} } = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 {\sqrt a} \dfrac {|2 a x + b|} {2 a x + b} \cosh^{-1} \left({\dfrac {|2 a x + b|} {\sqrt {b^2 - 4 a c} } }\right) & : b^2 - 4 a c > 0 \\ 
\dfrac 1 {\sqrt a} \sinh^{-1} \left({\dfrac {2 a x + b} {\sqrt {4 a c - b^2} } }\right) & : b^2 - 4 a c < 0 \\ \dfrac 1 {\sqrt a} \ln |2 a x + b| + C & : b^2 - 4 a c = 0
\end{cases}$

b) For $a < 0$ we have:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} } = \dfrac {-1} {\sqrt {-a} } \arcsin \left({\dfrac {2 a x + b} {\sqrt {|b^2 - 4 a c|} } }\right)$

defined only when $b^2 - 4 a c \ne 0$.

The technique I used was to complete the square in $a x^2 + b x + c$ to get $\dfrac {(2 a x + b)^2 - (b^2 - 4 a c)} {4 a}$ and use that as the basis for a primitive of the form:

$\displaystyle \frac 1 A \int \dfrac {\mathrm d z} {\pm z^2 \pm D^2}$

where $z = 2 a x + b$ and $D^2 = b^2 - 4 a c$ and $\dfrac 1 A$ is the constant that arises during the substitution.

Having evaluated both cases arising from different discriminant signs when $a < 0$, the result I obtained seemed to indicate that they could both be merged by using a modulus operation.

I also noted that when $a < 0$ the expression $a^2 + b x + c$ appears always negative when $b^2 - 4 a c$, hence the lack of definition of the primitive when those two conditions hold simultaneously.

I have been working with respect to Spiegel's "Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables" (Schaum, 1968), item $14.280$.

The latter appears to be incomplete, giving merely:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} } = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 {\sqrt a} \ln (2 \sqrt a \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} + 2 a x + b) \\ 
-\dfrac 1 {\sqrt {-a} } \sin^{-1} \left({\dfrac {2 a x + b} {\sqrt {b^2 - 4 a c} } }\right) \text { or } \dfrac 1 {\sqrt a} \sinh^{-1} \left({\dfrac {2 a x + b} {\sqrt {4 a c - b^2} } }\right)
\end{cases}$

without providing the conditions under which the various results hold.

He also appears to have glossed over the cases arising from different discriminant signs when $a < 0$ in the arcsin expression.

(I established to my satisfaction that the $\ln$ expression given by Spiegel is actually equivalent to the $\cosh^{-1}$ expression, give or take a constant that can be subsumed into the arbitrary constant of integration, but again, I may have made a mistake on that, so checking of my work would be greatly appreciated here.)

Comment: "Primitive root" says your question's title...?

Comment: good call. Fixed.

Comment: Then you must mean "primitive function of" ...

Comment: Must I? My understanding is that "primitive of $f(x)$" is understood to be an acceptable shorthand for "the indefinite integral of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$". If such abbreviated style is unacceptable, then no doubt someone will fix it, if they think it's necessary.

Comment: I guess you can write as you wish. To me it looked funny and I wasn't sure what it means until I read the question. But I suppose it couild be ok...within some fixed realm of study.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the term "primitive" for "indefinite integral" was standard terminology that is considered general mathematical knowledge. As you suggest, it may well not be so after all. Again, good call.